# How do I add in CSS style a class name that has a variable value?

Tags: css

I have a lot of tables that have different names like: my-table-1590 , my-table-1400, my-table-1121 , and so on.

I want to add in CSS, one custom style that should change all these tables together.

For example, i want instead of all these individual style code:

```
#my-table-1590 .my-table--desktop .my-table-product-0 {
background-color: red;
}

#my-table-1400 .my-table--desktop .my-table-product-0 {
background-color: red;
}

#my-table-1121 .my-table--desktop .my-table-product-0 {
background-color: red;
}
```

...

I want to add only one code that will change all tables (including future tables that i will make).

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks in advance for all the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select all IDs that **start** with `#my-table-` as follows.

```
  [id^="my-table-"] .my-table--desktop .my-table-product-0 {
       background-color: red;
  }
```

> ..the carat symbol. It's most commonly used in regular expressions to designate the beginning of a string.

Comment: Paulie, Thank you very much!! Yes this is what i was looking for, i guess this should work for me. Now i'll dig more into your suggestion and how to make it work for me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all of your tables have the same structure inside them, with the actual element you want to make red always having the class `.my-table-product-0`.

So can't you just use the following code?

```css
.my-table-product-0 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

---

If this isn't possible for some reason, add another class, such as `.red-table`, to all of the tables so that you can target them like this:

```css
.red-table .my-table--desktop .my-table-product-0 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

This is exactly what classes (that apply to several elements) and not ids (which apply to single elements) are for.

---

Alternatively, for cases where the structure is not always the same, you can use CSS variables. Declare a variable somewhere like this:

```
html {
  --table-color: red;
}
```

And then use it on all of your tables:

```css
#my-table-1590 .my-table--desktop .my-table-product-0 {
  background-color: var(--table-color);
}

#my-table-1400 .my-table--desktop .my-table-product-0 {
  background-color: var(--table-color);
}

#my-table-1121 .my-table--desktop .my-table-product-0 {
  background-color: var(--table-color);
}

...
```

Comment: Indeed for some reason it's not working to add only ".my-table-product-0". It's working only when i specifically add the table name "#my-table-XXXX".

Comment: @traykaleel That suggests that some other style is being applied to `my-table-product-0`, and a higher specificity (such as an `id`) is need to override this style. The code `.my-table-product-0 {background-color: red !important;}` would probably work in this case, although many people would discourage overusing the CSS `!important` statement.

Comment: Yes that could be the case with my code also. Although I tried a few times but it didn't help. Now after all the comments here, i guess i made a mistake somewhere (i have a very "bushy" structure :) ). I will have to try more!! Thank U!!

Answer (score 0):

You could try by using CSS variables:

Declaration:

```
--main-color: black;
```

Usage:

```
color: var(--main-color);
```

More on this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties).